# Finding most common occurrence of a character that follows another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a small piece of code and I seem to have run into a roadblock. I was wondering if it's possible to (because I cannot, for the life of me, figure it out) find the most common occurrence of a character that *follows* a specific character or string?

For example, say I have the following sentence:

```
"this is a test sentence that happens to be short"
```

How would could I determine, for example, the most common character that occurs after the letter `h`?

In this specific example, doing it by hand, I get something like this:

`{"i": 1, "a": 2, "o": 1}`

I'd then like to be able to get the key of the highest value--in this case, `a`.

Using `Counter` from `collections`, I've been able to find the most common occurrence of a specific word or character, but I'm not sure how to do this specific implementation of doing the most common occurrence *after*. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

(The code I wrote to find the most common occurrence of a letter in a file: 
 `Counter(text).most_common(1)`, which does include white spaces )

EDIT:

How would this be done with words? For example, if I had the sentence: `"whales are super neat, but whales don't make good pets. whales are cool."`
How would I find the most common character that occurs after the words `whales`? 
In this instance, removing white spaces, the most common character would be `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a solution without using regex:

```py
import collections
sentence = "this is a test sentence that happens to be short" 
characters = [sentence[i] for i in range(1,len(sentence)) if sentence[i-1] == 'h']

most_common_char = collections.Counter(characters).most_common(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just split them by your character and then get the letter after it

```
import collections
sentence = "this is a test sentence that happens to be short"
character = 'h'
letters_after_some_character = [part[0] for part in str.split(character)[1:] if part[0].isalpha()]
print(collections.Counter(letters_after_some_character).most_common())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Counter` class we can try:

```
import collections
s = "this is a test sentence that happens to be short"
s = re.sub(r'^.*n|\s*', '', s)
print(collections.Counter(s).most_common(1)[0])
```

The above would print `o` as it is the most frequent character occurring after the *last* `n`.  Note that we also strip off whitespace before calling collections count.

Comment: This looks interesting - I'l have to check out that counter class. btw, the question suggests 'h' as the char to look for.

Comment: Using `h` as the search character is a bad choice IMO, because `h` occur both very early and very late in the string.